# What is the Apache Beam way to handle 'routing'

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using Apache Beam I am doing computations - and if they succeed I'd like to write the output to one sink, and if there is a failure I'd like to write that to another sink.

**Is there any way to handle metadata or content based routing in Apache Beam?**

I've used Apache Camel extensively, and so in my mind based on the outcome of a previous transform, I should route a message to a different sink using a [router](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html) (perhaps determined by a metadata flag I set on the message header). Is there an analogous capability with Apache Beam, or would I instead just have a sequential transform that inspects the PCollection and handles writing to sinks within the transform?

Ideally I'd like this logic (written verbosely for attempted clarity)

```
result = my_pcollections | 'compute_stuff' >> beam.Map(lambda (pcollection): my_compute_func(pcollection))
result | ([success_failure_router]
   | 'sucess_sink' >> beam.io.WriteToText('/path/to/file')
   | 'failure_sink' >> beam.io.WriteStringsToPubSub('mytopic'))
```

However.. I suspect the 'Beam' way of handling this is

```
result = my_pcollections | 'compute_stuff' >> beam.Map(lambda (pcollection): my_compute_func(pcollection))
result | 'write_results_appropriately' >> write_results_appropriately(result))
...
def write_results_appropriately(result):
   if result == ..:
      # success, write to file
   else:
      # failure, write to topic
```

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

**High-level:**

I am not sure of specifics of the Python API in this case, but from high level it looks like this:

- par-dos support multiple outputs;
- outputs are identified by the tag you give them (e.g. "correct-elements", "invalid-elements");
- in your main par-do you write to multiple outputs choosing the output using your criteria;
- each output is represented by a separate `PCollection`;
- then you get the separate `PCollections` representing the tagged outputs from your par-do;
- then apply different sinks to each of the tagged `PCollections`;

In detail see the section
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs